# Rails app don't work on passenger after changing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I got rails app deployed on passanger with apache.
Before app works on local firebird database, after i changed credentials to database server in company but located on another pc i got this error.

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. 
Raw process output:
(empty)

Error ID
    06c3cb78
```

When i start rails app with this database on my local machine with `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` it works fine.
Does anybody got this error before and know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake. There was error with dns on server, my production server 'don't see database srv'